# How to redirect only when exact url matches?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect with apache .htaccess. I have the following codes

```
redirectMatch 301 /user http://clients.mydomain.com
```

it works pretty well, but I don't want **"/user/login"** to be directed to **"http://clients.mydomain.com/login"**.

How do I prevent it?

Answer (score 71):

Simple add a `^` to beginning and a `$` to the end

`^` tells tells the regex to match the beginning of the url

`$` tells tells the regex to match the end of the url

```
redirectMatch 301 ^/user$ http://clients.mydomain.com
```

So now your rule will only match `/user` and not `/some/user` or `/user/name` or `/some/user/name`

---

**NOTE:** If you want to match `/user/` and `/user` then use `^/user/?$`

`?` says to match the previous character/group zero to one times

Comment: Checking for the trailing / is a good idea. Firefox hides it so even though you think the url is /user it's actually being passed as /user/

Comment: But what if you have space characters ` `? You need double quotes to handle those properly. using escapes `\ ` in the regex of `Redirect` results in  the system thinking it's an extra parameters, rather than an escaped space. And if you have double quotes, you can't use `^` or `$` to specify exact matches

Answer (score 2):

Use a regex, you're already using redirect match.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch

'$' matches the end of the url. In your example:

```
redirectMatch 301 ^/user/(.+)$ http://clients.example.com/
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @caskey