# 301 Redirects from specific .html pages to new permalink structure failing

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, permalinks

I've been searching online for over an hour trying to find out why my .htaccess file isn't working as expected, but all the docs and questions about .htaccess seem to say everything should be fine. i am using a wordpress site now and need to redirect some old links to *.html files to new permalinks (one by one as the naming convention has changed completely). so my .htaccess file looks like this:

```
# Redirects for old URLs
redirect 301 /contact_us http://rpcdev.thisisforge.com/contact/
redirect 301 /about_us http://rpcdev.thisisforge.com/about/
redirect 301 /clients http://rpcdev.thisisforge.com/work/
redirect 301 /clients/event.html http://rpcdev.thisisforge.com/work/event-retail-design/
redirect 301 /clients/identity.html http://rpcdev.thisisforge.com/work/identity-branding/
redirect 301 /clients/web.html http://rpcdev.thisisforge.com/work/web-design/
redirect 301 /clients/corp_lit.html http://rpcdev.thisisforge.com/work/brochures-publications/

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

The First three are working fine, it's the ones from specific .html pages that are not. I've tried putting the code both above and below the WOrdPress code, and I've tried switching the order of my 301s so the .html redirects are first, not last. but this doesnt help. Weirdly, sometimes the corp_lit.html redirect works ok, but the others don't. i can see no rhyme or reason to this!

Is my browser or OS (windows s7) caching the 301s from the .htaccess or something, back from when they were maybe incorrectly typed? i've tried emptying browser cache and flushing DNS in command prompt, but to no avail.

Pull
Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Redirect directive links path nodes together, so your first /clients redirect is being applied instead of the following ones, try changing it to use RedirectMatch instead

```
 RedirectMatch 301 ^/clients/?$ http://rpcdev.thisisforge.com/work/
```

Comment: Thank you! All seems to be working now (Firefox does cache 301 redirects, so I was also struggling with any changes for that reason). Last question: in your revised code, does the trailing slash matter? I'm hoping that both "/clients" and "/clients/" will redirect to "/work/". It seems to be working for me, but just wanted to be sure that's officially correct.

Comment: Ah, I found the answer elsewhere to my last question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8217430/how-to-redirect-only-when-exact-url-matches) - it seems the ? allows for with or without the last character, so thank you again.